# Is Converting a Path To A Shape Possible?

Tags: c#, wpf

So i basically have a Stack Panel, And i'm using a foreach loop to iterate through the children, and all of the children are 'path' formats, but some are lines and some are ellipses (or were atleast, before converted to path)

My question is, how can i tell which ones are lines, and which ones are ellipses? , i'm using the isMouseOver event to check if the mouse is over Ellipses to make them change accordingly on MouseDown

```
private void GraphPanel_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var x in GraphPanel.Children)
        {

                if (((Path)x).IsMouseOver)
                {
                    var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
                    var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFB1D100");
                    ((Path)x).Stroke = brush;
                    ((Path)x).StrokeThickness = 8;
                }
                else
                {

                    ((Path)x).Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    ((Path)x).StrokeThickness = 4;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I would assume that an `Ellipses` does not have any straight lines, while `Lines` do not have curved lines, so you can check the `Path.Data` to see what kind of lines exist in the `Path`. If you scroll to the bottom of [MSDN's page on PathSegments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathsegment.aspx) you can see the different segment types available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the type of the [Path.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data.aspx) property, which is a class derived from [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx).

Besides some complex Geometry types, the basic derived Geometry types are [EllipseGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.ellipsegeometry.aspx), [LineGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.linegeometry.aspx) and [RectangleGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rectanglegeometry.aspx).

```
Path path = (Path)x;
Geometry geometry = path.Data;
if (geometry is EllipseGeometry)
{
    ...
}
else if (geometry is LineGeometry)
{
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way, but this is what I've Figured out

```
if((Path)x).Data.ToString() == "System.Windows.Media.EllipseGeometry"){}
```

Comment: That would better be written as `if (((Path)x).Data is System.Windows.Media.EllipseGeometry)`.